# Thymeleaf input date don't show and don't receive value with LocalDate

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf, localdate

I have in my form any inputs with date value, but don't show value. If I input the date when sent to backend don't receive this information. I use LocalDate

I'm use this dependencies:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf-layout-dialect</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-java8time</artifactId>
        <!-- <version>3.0.1.RELEASE</version>  -->
    </dependency>
```

Class

```
public class Prova {
   @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy")
   private LocalDate dataProva;
```

}

Controller

```
@PostMapping("/salvar")
public ModelAndView salvarProva(@ModelAttribute Prova prova, BindingResult result) {
    try {
        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            LOGGER.error("ERRO EM CAMPOS AO SALVAR PROVA {}", result.getAllErrors());
        }
                    
        if(prova.getId() != null) {
            provaService.alterar(prova);
        } else {
            
            if(provaService.existeProvaDataSituacao(prova.getDataProva(), SituacaoRealizacaoProvaEnum.ABERTA)) {
                throw new ValidacaoDadosException(String.format("JÁ EXISTE UMA PROVA EM ABERTO PARA A DATA {}", prova.getDataProva()));
            }
            provaService.adicinar(prova);
        }
        return listarProvas();
    } catch (ValidacaoDadosException e) {
        LOGGER.error("ERRO AO ADICIONAR/ALTERAR A PROVA ", e);
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("/admin/prova/form");
        mv.addObject("status", "501");
        mv.addObject("message", "Ocorreu o seguinte erro " + e);
        return mv;
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Do you have the `thymeleaf-extras-java8time` package too? 
https://www.baeldung.com/dates-in-thymeleaf

Comment: Yes, i put!
`
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-layout-dialect</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
      <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
      <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-java8time</artifactId>
      <!-- <version>3.0.1.RELEASE</version>  -->
  </dependency>
`

Comment: Can you update your question with the entire HTML with the form tag and the controller code?

Comment: I do not see `data` used anywhere, except declaration, in your code.

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash changed info, thanks

Comment: And where is that data declared? Your current code hints at that you placed in the controller, which is the wrong place. In your dependencies you don't need the additional thymeleaf dependencies they are part of the starter, also which version of Spring Boot are you using?

Comment: Excuse, I don't put the full information .. but now I formated with the class "Prova".
<version>2.7.2</version>

Comment: If I change to th:value="*{dataProva}" show in the view ... but  Controller don't receive

Answer (score -1):

here my form:

```
    <form th:action="@{/listaProvas/salvar}" method="post" th:object="${prova}" class="form-row espaco-form" ><!-- card-body -->
            <input th:field="*{id}" type="hidden" id="id">
            
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <label for="nome">Nome</label>
                <input id="nome" th:field="*{nome}" th:errorclass="is-invalid" class="form-control" placeholder="Nome da Prova"
                    onkeyup="this.value = this.value.toUpperCase()">
                <p class="alert alert-danger" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('nome')}" th:errors="*{nome}">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="row">
                    
                    <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
                        <label for="dataProva">Data Realização</label>
                        <div class="input-group date">
                            <input type="date" class="form-control" id="dataProva" th:field="*{dataProva}"/>
                        </div>
                        <p class="alert alert-danger" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('dataProva')}" th:errors="*{dataProva}">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12" style="margin-top: 5em;">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
                        <a class="btn btn-danger btn-lg btn-block" th:href="@{'/listaProvas'}" role="button">Voltar</a>
                    </div>
    
                    <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
                        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" id="button-submit" type="submit" role="button">Salvar</button>
                    </div>
                </div>  
            </div>  
        </form>
```

Comment: Don't add additional information as an answer, instead edit your question.